# Performance Issue with Java Code

Tags: java, mongodb

I am using java with mongodb.. I am getting performance issue in this below code can you please optimize this code?

I need to increase the performance of this function.

//first function which receives the parameter as associationId. can you guys please help me to increase the performance for this function..

```
public ArrayList<ResidentAssociationMapEntity> listUsersByAssociation(String 
associationId) {

HashMap<String, Object> filterExpressions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
filterExpressions.put("associationId", associationId);
filterExpressions.put("residentStatus", 1);
List<ResidentAssociationMapEntity> residents = 
    DBManager.getInstance().getByMultipleFields(
            ResidentAssociationMapEntity.class, filterExpressions);
    if (residents != null && residents.size() > 0) {
        for (ResidentAssociationMapEntity map : residents ) {
            map.setUser(getUser(map.getUserId()));
        }
    } 

    return new ArrayList<ResidentAssociationMapEntity>(residents);
}
```

// get user function

```
public UserEntity getUser(String userId) {

    UserEntity entity = DBManager.getInstance().getById(UserEntity.class, 
userId);
    ResidentAssociationMapEntity map = 
getResidentAssocaitionMap(entity.getUserId());
    if (map != null) {
        entity.setUnitNo(map.getUnitNumber() + "");
        entity.setAssociationId(map.getAssociationId());
entity.setAssociationName(CompanyDAO.getInstance().getCompany(map.getAssocia
tionId()).getName());

    }

    return entity;
}
```

//getResidentAssocaitionMap function

```
 private ResidentAssociationMapEntity getResidentAssocaitionMap(String 
 residentId) {

HashMap<String, Object> filterExpressions = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    filterExpressions.put("userId", residentId);
    filterExpressions.put("residentStatus", 1);
    List<ResidentAssociationMapEntity> residents = 
     DBManager.getInstance().getByMultipleFields(
            ResidentAssociationMapEntity.class, filterExpressions);
    if (residents != null && residents.size() > 0) {
        return residents.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us a bit about `DBManager` class? Does it interact with mongo? Can you post that class as well? Also add how much time these three methods are taking to complete the tasks?

Comment: Its taking approximately 2 minutes from postman.. Yes DB Manager is a class which connects to db.

Comment: Please let me know how to use left join in this so i can resolve this issue.

Comment: Inside `getUser` method, you are calling `DBManager.getInstance().getById(UserEntity.class, 
userId);` too many times. Looks like this is cpu intensive operation consuming lot of resources. You shouldn't be calling cpu intensive operations in a loop!

Comment: Get all `UserEntity` objects in a set or list and then iterate through the object rather hitting the `DBManager` class.

Comment: I've no idea of your domain/data model! Hence, can't advice on left join